# Using dependency in pom.xml and getting authorization error

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.dean.jraw</groupId>
     <artifactId>JRAW</artifactId>
     <version>${jraw.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml file, but I am getting this error:

```
Authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/net/dean/jraw/JRAW/1.1.0/JRAW-1.1.0.pom 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: did u add proxies in your settings.xml file?

Comment: Please read the details here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

Answer (score 1):

The referenced repository requires authentication. You can configure the repository inside your project's pom.xml file, but authentication data is sensitive information and should go in your Maven installation's settings.xml file, as suggested in [Servers configuration](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).

Comment: how do i get the username password for this repository?

Comment: They should be provided by the repository owner. In this case, as @khmarbaise pointed out in the suggested link, that specific repository is for Spring team members only.

Answer (score 0):

[As announced by JFrog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020), anonymous access is no longer supported:

> We will no longer support anonymous download of 3rd-party Maven Central artifacts from repo.spring.io, even if previously cached by an authenticated user. They should be resolved instead from the central servers.

To download artifacts anonymously, you'll have to add a central server such as jcenter. So I'd suggest you add a repository in pom.xml as below:

```
<repository>
  <id>jcenter</id>
  <name>jcenter</name>
  <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
```