# Maven clean and install returns 401 on resolving some dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to clean and install a Maven project. This is the first time I am doing anything like this and am running into a few issues that I don't know what to do about:

The stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.twmacinta:fast-md5:pom:2.7.1 from/to maven-twacinta (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): Access denied to https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/twmacinta/fast-md5/2.7.1/fast-md5-2.7.1.pom. Error code 401, 
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:889)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:659)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: io.takari.aether.connector.AuthorizationException: Access denied to https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/twmacinta/fast-md5/2.7.1/fast-md5-2.7.1.pom. Error code 401, 
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.handleResponseCode(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:397)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.access$8(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:391)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:603)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:481)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:915)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:331)
```

Access is being denied to a specific dependency. When I go to the link, it asks me for a username and password. Link: [https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/twmacinta/fast-md5/2.7.1/fast-md5-2.7.1.pom [1](https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/twmacinta/fast-md5/2.7.1/fast-md5-2.7.1.pom)

I suspect that the username and password are either wrong or not being supplied at all. My questions:

1. Where are the username and password specified? Where can I find what username and password is being used here if at all.
2. Anyone know the username and password for this repo or a workaround?
3. Any other insights to solve this? This code works on someone's laptop that I am trying to take over. Trouble is, it works for them out of the box and they too dont know why!

Comment: Can you add the dependency you are using in the pom?

Comment: Manuel: The dependency is already there in the pom.xml:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twmacinta/fast-md5 -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twmacinta</groupId>
      <artifactId>fast-md5</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: i think it is missing a username and password?

Answer (score 1):

The configurations for repositories (and their passwords) are usually in the `settings.xml` in the user directory under `.m2`.

You probably need to copy it from your colleague.

Comment: ok. thanks fabian. will try and post back here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the username/password, it is feasible to download the dependencies anonymously. Please refer to my answer in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68645965/13050402